# Modifying PDO script to use functions, more efficient and less sequential

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've spent a few days making a script that essentially takes some data on a db2 system and creates new records for it in a mysql system. Along the way, it does some checks and I use looping to base inserts or updates on those conditions.

This script works, it returns what I expect and inserts/updates as expected. I've tested it for the deletion process, updates, inserts, whether records are expired or not......basically every function of this script I have tested thoroughly.

I feel like it's not as fast as it could be, it's probably more sequential and redundant than it should be as well.

I'm not used to working with PDO in a script like this, but I'm wondering what I could do here to fix performance/speed and redundancy. I know some of the logic may 'seem' redundant, but the logic is exactly where it needs to be, I'm just wondering if I could/should use functions to reduce calls or loops possibly.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You already asked the same question on codereview, and I answered it. You then deleted the question, and the answer, and you've posted virtually the same question here. From your title I understand you've read my response. That kind of behavior deserves a downvote, I think.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is tricky, I will get dragged over the hot coals for this, 1) you may want to not use PDO at all if you are sure that there is no risk of direct injection attack, 2) also I would look at implementing this sort of feature via [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) i.e. via acron job on a curl trigger

In general PDO is a very expensive way to run a query. A simple string under `mysqli_query()` would be about 2.5x more efficient.

Comment: Man, I wish I would have known that before I started porting over 500,000 records ! haha. There is no risk of injection attack, whatsoever. this is a locally running script that runs nightly

Comment: I would be happy using `mysqli_query()` you may also want to use `PHP` in `PHP CLI` mode (basically bash via `crontab` then and have a log file you get emailed at the end etc) this is because CLI is faster anyway, faster for batch processing and doesn't time out

Comment: Ok. So would I effectively go through this script and replace my PDO connections with the old mysqli/odbc_connect and then just change out my prepare/execute points to match?

Comment: yes it's not hard to get something more streamlined. you have the logic, so it's just cut n paste into the new methods.. you may be surprised that there is a lot less to write tho.. you'll have less code than you do now.. also I guess if you used CLI and mysqli-query you'd get close to 3.5x speed increase

Comment: may I just say I have done this across entire universities campuses, and replicated data bi-directionally into SEVEN systems concurrently nightly and deliberately never used PDO, so I am experienced in this.. and when the entire campus computer system crashed this didn't and it rebuilt everything in about 20 minutes.. but hey this is `SO` so I get marked down .. love trolls

Comment: What exactly do you mean with not using PDO if there is no risk of an injection attack? You seem to be suggesting that either mysqli is less secure or that you don't need prepared statements. Both of which I disagree with by the way.

Comment: not sure what you are on about mate, `mysqli_query` is operationally simpler... it's basically ODBC over streamlined interfaces if you remove the prepared statements SQL becomes text parsed into a driver via a port.. and it awaits  a response.. there are no "objects" to balloon into memory and trivial memory overheads except at the response phase, where you *may* get a grid, which (if you do) is maximally 2D in pointer terms.. ... he's using DB2 anyway `raw SQL` is safe to use if you are making hand made strings you know exactly what they contain, if it is speed is you are after

Comment: On your `1)` point, please do not infer that `mysqli` is less secure and unable to handle SQL Injection Attacks that *only* PDO can do.

Comment: @MrHeelis can we possibly discuss one quick point in chat? if you're able